# Rule based symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rule-based

I want to make a rule-based symbology with two classes: one class with all the empty cells in a given column and one class for the cells that do have a value in it.

In Excel I would use something like ISEMPTY, but I can't find the QGIS counterpart.

Comment: Python has nothing to do with this. The check you're looking for is `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.